# Make div children share the parents width

Tags: html, css

Basically I got a div parent that consists of 1+ div child elements (with a button within each one). 
Now I'd like the buttons to fill the entire width of the parent - but share it.
That is, if there's one child button it should fill 100% - if there are 2 they should have a width of 50% of the size each etc.

How can I do this?

Edit: As requested - here's the code (although I think the above explanation is better):

```
.buttons
{
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 34px;
}

.submitbutton
{
    width: inherit;
    background: #C2E5FC; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C2E5FC 0%, #008BE8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C2E5FC), color-stop(100%,#008BE8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C2E5FC 0%,#008BE8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C2E5FC 0%,#008BE8 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C2E5FC 0%,#008BE8 100%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#C2E5FC', endColorstr='#008BE8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #C2E5FC 0%,#008BE8 100%); /* W3C */
    border: 1px solid #008BE8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px #008BE8;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The html:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <input class="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Register">
    <input class="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Cancel">
</div>
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Does the parent div have a set width?

Comment: @j08691
I've updated with the code

Comment: Is using JavaScript/jQuery an option?

Comment: I assume that you expect the css to conform to any number of child elements, is that right?

Comment: @ogc-nick
Yes that is right

Comment: You could probably use javascript somehow like get the number of children in of the div, and then calculate the percentage for each.

Comment: This require some sort of calculation and conditional logic so you need javascript for this; can't do it with just CSS.

Comment: If this is static html/css and javascript is not an option then you cannot do what you suggest. If you are using a preprocessor like php then you can output some inline styles that will do what you want. If you can use JS then you can adjust the styles after the elements are loaded. Without that I do not think there is a way. I hope someone can come up with an answer though I would be very interested.

Comment: @JordanAxe Do you really want all of them to be of equal size? Similar behaviour could be implemented with tables and obviously with 'DIV's with display table & table-cell. But, the buttons wont be of equal size, and it varies with the value/text in it. Well, the buttons altogether takes up the entire width. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/8LmXt/4/

Answer (score 2):

You can enclose them inside a li and use this css:

```
.buttons > li {
display: table-cell !important; 
width: 1% !important;
float: none !important;
}

.buttons > li >* {
width:100%
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipinroshan/kpdZM/)
[image: Jsfiddle view]

Comment: Nice solution. You don't *have* to enclose them in a `<li>` element. Divs with `display: table-cell` work equally as well (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kpdZM/1/)).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to avoid adding additional markup using pure CSS, Flexbox is what you're looking for.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/qekml

```
.buttons {
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.submitbutton {
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Most browsers support some version of Flexbox, but IE doesn't support it until version 10 (see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).  Be aware that while older Webkit browsers (including mobile) do support Flexbox, it [doesn't work on buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961192/flexbox-doesnt-work-with-buttons), which is why I've omitted properties for those browsers.

If you require better browser support than this, you'll need to use an extra element.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/gefz5oxi

```
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="foo"><input class="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Register"></div>
  <div class="foo"><input class="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Cancel"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.buttons {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* optional */
}

.foo {
  display: table-cell;
}

.foo .submitbutton {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the child element widths as a percentage or their parent. Something like this:

```
<div id="parent" style="width:1000px;">
<div id="child1" style="width:25%"></div>
<div id="child2" style="width:25%"></div>
<div id="child3" style="width:25%"></div>
<div id="child4" style="width:25%"></div>
</div>
```

In this situation each child element will have a width of 250px.

As per your request, here's the same thing using CSS classes:

```
<style type="text/css">
.parent {
    width:1000px;
}
.child {
    width:25%;
}
</style>
<div id="parent" class="parent">
<div id="child1" class="child"></div>
<div id="child2" class="child"></div>
<div id="child3" class="child"></div>
<div id="child4" class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see - however I'd like to define it in css and have it some-how define the widths automatically.

Comment: Updated the code for you. Both examples provide the same end result. By the way, using `style="width:25%"` is defining it in CSS, except for I'm doing it without classes.

Comment: The asker does not know the number of children ahead of time.

Comment: Apologies, didn't read that comment. In that case, as is already mentioned, I would get the number of child elements and set the child element width using JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure how many childbuttons you will have, you can work with some failsafe classes for your childs.

e.g. something like

```
.grid4button { width: 25%; }
.grid3button { width: 33.33333% }
.grid2button { width: 50%; }
```

etc (i guess you get it)

now you need some js that checks for the number of childbuttons and appends the needed classname to each of those buttons.

EDIT:

```
var childs = $(".buttons").children().length;
$('buttons .submitbutton').addClass('grid'+childs+'button');
```

could be an examplatory js check with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

As much as tables are dépassé, I would just use a table with one row () and dynamically add cells () for each button. Give the  width:100% and you're about done. Most js frameworks that implement Toolbar classes use tables.