# Allow inline block elements to stretch fluidly and collapse and stack as viewports shrink

Tags: responsive-design, css

Given the following code, I would like to find a way to have a series of inline-block elements stretch the full width of the parent element while stacking on top of each other as the line wraps.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Example**

If all children have the same min-width, I want this to create a grid effect.  For example, on larger screens, the children may stack 5 across until they wrap onto a second line.  I would like those all to be 20% (1/5) of the available width.  As the screen shrinks, the fifth and 10th items wrap leaving two rows of 4 items and a third row of 2 items.  Now I would like to have the children all stretch 25% (1/4) of the available width except for the last row of two children.  Those should be 50% each.

**Attempts**

I've tried floating the children, making them inline-blocks and I've experimented with flex-box, but none of them are giving me the result I desire.  Inline-blocks have come the closest, allowing them to stack as with parent width shrinks, but I can't achieve the stretching.

**Restrictions**

I'd prefer not to use media queries as I would then need to write in the exact breakpoints for this example then alter all of them if anything changes in the site layout.  I'd like to find a more organic way to solve this problem.

Javascript is out.  I want to find a way to do this with just CSS.

Comment: My first thought is that without JS, and without media queries, you can't. You'll need *something* that notices how many items are on one line. I can't figure out how to do that without one of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make div children share the parents width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340120/make-div-children-share-the-parents-width)

Comment: @Chris - define larger screen, define a shrinked large screen. Can you? You can't - so you need to define some breakpoints to sort this with css only. Media queries are currently the only way to control responsive layouts.

Comment: When you can specify width for elements, it is not tricky. Try to do it when you can specify only max-width to children except the last, and the last one last child has to occupy the rest of the width after all other have occupied theirs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many thanks to Chris Coyier and CSS Tricks.  Flexbox is indeed the answer.  Rather than copy and paste his solution, here's the link to his Pen: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/yCeax. If you are interested in his whole thought about it, here is the blog post to it: http://css-tricks.com/filling-space-last-row-flexbox/

Here's the actual solution, just in case the CodePen goes away.

**HTML**

```
<button id="add">Add Child</button>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 25%;
  border: 5px solid white;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .child {
    min-width: 33.33%; 
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .child {
    min-width: 50%; 
  }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#add").on("click", function() {
  $("#parent").append("<div class='child' />");
});
```

Comment: We would prefer that you "cape pasted" his solution, and possibly even  write what he did there. If the article or codepen goes down, this answer is useless and anyone looking for a similar problem will not be able to get anything from it.