# Dynamic Inline form in angular using material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I am trying to build a dynamic form with the help of angular material. The requirement is the I need two input columns in one row and the number of input values can be dynamic. Is there any way such that I can build this form using `ng-repeat` with two input box in one row.

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using ng-repeat, I can build the form but the problem is two input box in a row.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap ? Create a fiddle and provide us the link

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/Zu8CPGymfHVKt83S4SzA/preview using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099394/allow-inline-block-elements-to-stretch-fluidly-and-collapse-and-stack-as-viewpor?stw=2). I am not sure how efficient this solution is, but it will surely give you a start.

CSS

```
    .myrow {
       display: flex;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
   .mygrid {
       flex: 1;
       min-width: 25%;
       padding : 10px;
   }
```

HTML

```
<form name="userFormTwo" novalidate>
      <div class="myrow">
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="user in formDataTwo.users" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userFieldForm.email.$invalid }">
          <div class="mygrid">
            <ng-form name="userFieldForm">
              <label>{{ user.name }}'s Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required>
              <p class="help-block" ng-show="userFieldForm.email.$invalid">Valid Email Address Required</p>
            </ng-form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fQxlxt7LkxKlQYBV0uPC?p=preview)**

You can also use bootstrap class(`row` and `col-xs-12`), but then you'll have to tweak your `ng-repeat` to loop with the increment of `2`, to accommodate a pair of array elements in a single row, which would ultimately require some extra effort on the controller part just for that.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using bootstrap, you need to use `form-inline` class. Check the below code.

```
<form name="userFormTwo" class="form-inline" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="user in formDataTwo.users" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userFieldForm.email.$invalid }">
        <ng-form name="userFieldForm">
            <label>{{ user.name }}'s Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required>
            <p class="help-block" ng-show="userFieldForm.email.$invalid">Valid Email Address Required</p>
        </ng-form>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think it won't show two input box in a row.

Comment: How do you say that ? Have you tried atleast ? You need to check the output in desktop view