# Flex box to not shrink an item to invisibility

Tags: css, flexbox

This is my very first usage of CSS flexbox layout. I have two items I want to align in a row, for a mobile page layout: A button and a text box. The button comes left and should take whatever space it normally needs. The textbox comes right and should fill all remaining space - but no more!

With this code, the textbox does fill almost the entire row, leaving only a few pixels left for the button which is by far not enough to show it completely. The button can't hold its necessary size against the stretched textbox. What's wrong?

```
<div id="mobile-tools">
<input type="button" id="navigation-button" ...>
<div id="search-box"><input type="search" ...></div>
</div>

#mobile-tools
{
    display: flex;
}
#navigation-button
{
    flex: 0;
}
#search-box
{
    flex: 1;
}
#search-box input[type="search"]
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Webkit prefixes left away for brevity of the example. Testing in latest stable Desktop Chrome for now, later also in stable/beta Android Chrome and current Android Firefox.

Comment: By Removing `width: 100%;` make any impact?

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961192/flexbox-doesnt-work-with-buttons

Comment: Removing the 100% will not stretch the textbox anywhere. The button has a text on it and the text should be visible completely in one line. No more space should be taken by the button. Just a regular "AutoSize" as I'd use it in WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your button a flex-basis value:

http://jsfiddle.net/rrGp7/2/

```
#navigation-button {
    flex: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. From reading the MDN introduction and another page on this, being completely confused, I thought this "auto" was one of the defaults.

Comment: @LonelyPixel: `flex: 0 auto` is equivalent to the initial value, so it doesn't even need to be specified - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrGp7/3/).

Comment: To tell you the truth, I think this might be an error in Webkit/Blink.  If you read the spec, it explicitly states "flex items won't shrink below their minimum content size (the length of the longest word or fixed-size element)".  (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/#flex-initial)