# "display: flex" on <button> versus on <span>

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a question about the calculation of the width of flex containers. The  element seems to behave differently to other elements in this regard.

If I add the style `"display: flex"` to a `<span>` element containing text, it takes 100% of its parent's width.

If I add the same style to a `<button>` element, its width is calculated according to its textual content.

How is this so? Which (implicit) CSS rule on the `<button>` element generates this behaviour? And how can I switch between both behaviours?

(I've tested this in Firefox and in Chrome. I could as well have taken a `<div>` instead of a `<span>`.)

Comment: Here is a good link that might help with what you are looking for:    http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`display: flex` works to an extent on buttons in webkit based browsers such as Chrome and Safari, though the behaviour of the button and its flex children is buggy. It does not work at all in Firefox, and this might be technically *the correct behaviour* — [here is a related bug report.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869)

If you want to use `display: flex` on a button, place the property on a child div. To have the button stretch to fit its parent, give it `width: 100%;`.

```css
button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
button > div {
  display: flex;
}
button > div > div {
  flex: 2;
  background: #F00;
}
button > div > div:first-child {
  background: #F90;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div>
    <div>Hello, I am button div 1</div>
    <div>Hello, I am button div 2</div>
  </div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox doesn't work on buttons. You might find this article helpful.

[flexbox-doesnt-work-with-buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961192/flexbox-doesnt-work-with-buttons)