# HTML + CSS: Anchor takes up full width when display flex, but button does not

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button that has the same styles as an anchor tag.

However, I noticed that the width of the anchor tag is the full width of the parent, while the button is only the width of its contents when I add `display: flex`

```
const App = () => {
  const buttonRef = useRef();
  return(
    <div className="box">
      <a className="link" href="/blah">hey</a>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(buttonRef.current);
        }}
        ref={buttonRef}
        className="link">
          Special Button
       </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css:

```
.link {
  display: flex;
  justify-contents: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Why are they different widths when they both have the same styles?

Here's my codepen using react: https://codepen.io/edmundmai/pen/qBRewxX

Comment: Links are `display: inline`, buttons are `display: inline-block`. They're going to behave differently. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Phix OP is changing the default display

Comment: make the parent display:grid or display:flex + flex-direction:column; so it becomes a child grid/flex and its display and defaut behavior is overriden. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZELgNLJ . `justify-content` is whithout  `s` btw.

Comment: Not only for button, it does not take full width with `display: flex` for all default `inline-block` elements (such as select, input).
Here is the link: https://codepen.io/prakashmari/pen/rNyNroo

Comment: Solution was to use `display: inline-flex`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217058/display-flex-on-button-versus-on-span?rq=4) it's actually the button tag that isn't acting properly.

Either, set the button to `width: 100%` or wrap it in a parent that has `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`